# How to convert inline SQL queries to JOINS in SQL SERVER to reduce load time

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I need help in optimizing this SQL query.

In the main `SELECT` statement there are three columns which is dependent on the outer query result. This is why my query is taking a long time to return data. I have tried making left joins but this is not working properly.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT ou.OrganizationUserID AS StudentID, 
  ou.FirstName, 
  ou.LastName, 
  (
    SELECT 
      STRING_AGG(
        (ug.UG_Name), 
        ','
      ) 
    FROM 
      Groups ug 
      INNER JOIN ApplicantUserGroup augm ON augm.AUGM_UserGroupID = ug.UG_ID 
    WHERE 
      augm.AUGM_OrganizationUserID = ou.OrganizationUserID 
      AND ug.UG_IsDeleted = 0 
      AND augm.AUGM_IsDeleted = 0
  ) AS UserGroups, 
  order1.OrderNumber AS OrderId -- UAT-2455         
  , 
  (
    SELECT 
      STRING_AGG(
        (CActe.CustomAttribute), 
        ','
      ) 
    FROM 
      CustomAttributeCte CActe 
    WHERE 
      CActe.HierarchyNodeID = dpm.DPM_ID 
      AND CActe.OrganizationUserID = ps.OrganizationUserID
  ) AS CustomAttributes -- UAT-2455
  , 
  (
    SELECT 
      STRING_AGG(
        (CActe.CustomAttributeID), 
        ','
      ) 
    FROM 
      CustomAttributeCte CActe 
    WHERE 
      CActe.HierarchyNodeID = dpm.DPM_ID 
      AND CActe.OrganizationUserID = ps.OrganizationUserID
  ) AS CustomAttributeID 
FROM 
  ApplicantData acd WITH (NOLOCK) 
  INNER JOIN ClientPackage ps WITH (NOLOCK) ON acd.ClientSubscriptionID = ps.ClientSubscriptionID 
  INNER JOIN [ClientOrder] order1 WITH (NOLOCK) ON order1.OrderID = ps.OrderID 
  AND order1.IsDeleted = 0 
  INNER JOIN OUser ou WITH (NOLOCK) ON ou.OrganizationUserID = ps.OrganizationUserID
```

Comment: “mysql” ***or*** “SQL Server”? These are entirely different databases. Update the incorrect tag/text.

Comment: @user2864740, Question is basically related to SQL SERVER

Comment: Then *remove* “mysql” from the tags.

Comment: For performance help, you *must* include table *and* index definitions, as well as share a query plan (you can do this via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan). This is not answerable without that information. Why do you have `NOLOCK`, do you know what it does, do you have blocking problems you are trying to solve? It is not a go-faster switch, it is a give-incorrect-results switch, and can cause more problems than it solves

Comment: You can do the second and third `STRING_AGG` inside a single `APPLY`, to avoid querying that table twice. Why is `DISTINCT` there, I suspect that is probably your main issue, do you have duplicates you are trying to remove? If so why are there duplicates, which join is causing them?

Comment: Charlieface mentioned this: to help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need more information. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this query can be simplified, *and* the dependent subqueries in your SELECT clause removed, Consider your second and third dependent subqueries. You can refactor them into one nondependent subquery with a LEFT JOIN. Using nondependent subqueries is more efficient because the query planner can run them just once, rather than once for each row.

You want two `STRING_AGG()` results from the same table. This subquery gives those two outputs for every possible combination of `HierarchyNodeID` and  `OrganizationUserID` values. `STRING_AGG()` is an aggregate function like `SUM()` and so works nicely with `GROUP BY`.

```sql
      SELECT HierarchyNodeID, OrganizationUserID,
             STRING_AGG((CActe.CustomAttribute), ',') CustomAttributes -- UAT-2455,
             STRING_AGG((CActe.CustomAttributeID), ',') CustomAttributeIDs -- UAT-2455
        FROM CustomAttributeCte CActe
       GROUP BY HierarchyNodeID, OrganizationUserID
```

You can run this subquery itself to convince yourself it works.

Now, we can LEFT JOIN that into your query.  Like this. (For readability I took out the NOLOCKs and used JOIN: it means the same thing as INNER JOIN.)

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
       ou.OrganizationUserID AS StudentID,
       ou.FirstName,
       ou.LastName,
       'tempvalue' AS UserGroups,  -- shortened for testing
       order1.OrderNumber AS OrderId, -- UAT-2455
       uat2455.CustomAttributes,      -- UAT-2455
       uat2455.CustomAttributeIDs     -- UAT-2455
  FROM ApplicantData acd
  JOIN ClientPackage ps 
               ON acd.ClientSubscriptionID = ps.ClientSubscriptionID
  JOIN ClientOrder order1 
               ON order1.OrderID = ps.OrderID
              AND order1.IsDeleted = 0
  JOIN OUser ou
               ON ou.OrganizationUserID = ps.OrganizationUserID
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT HierarchyNodeID, OrganizationUserID,
             STRING_AGG((CActe.CustomAttribute), ',') CustomAttributes -- UAT-2455,
             STRING_AGG((CActe.CustomAttributeID), ',') CustomAttributeIDs -- UAT-2455
        FROM CustomAttributeCte CActe
       GROUP BY HierarchyNodeID, OrganizationUserID
     ) uat2455 
               ON uat2455.HierarchyNodeID = dpm.DPM_ID
              AND uat2455.OrganizationUserId = ps.OrganizationUserID
```

See how we collapsed your second and third dependent subqueries to just one, then used it as a virtual table with LEFT JOIN? We transformed the WHERE clauses from the dependent subqueries into an ON clause.

You can test this: run it with TOP(50) and eyeball the results.

When you're happy, the next step is to transform your first dependent subquery the same way.

**Pro tip** Don't use `WITH (NOLOCK)`, ever, unless a database administration expert tells you to after looking at *your specific query.*  If your query's purpose is a historical report and you *don't care whether the most recent transactions in your database are represented exactly right*, you can precede your query with this statement. It also allows the query to run while avoiding locks.

```sql
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
```

**Pro tip** Be obsessive about formatting your queries for readability. You, your colleagues, and yourself a year from now *must* be able to read and reason about queries like this.